# 一度獲得した権限はその後信用度が減ったとしても失いませんか？

Tags: サポート, 権限

単純なる疑問なのですが、表題のとおりです。

[権限 - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

たとえば、
信用度100で**コミュニティ Wiki の編集**の権限を得ますが、
一度信用度が101になった段階で信用度が99に減ったときに、
**コミュニティ Wiki の編集**の権限は持ったままかそうでないか気になります。

Answer (score 12, accepted):

信用度の減少に合わせて、基準を満たさなくなった権限も失います。

良質な投稿などでサイトに貢献することで信用度が貯まり、できることが増えます。反対に、投稿が多数のマイナス投票を受けて信用度を失えば、できることも制限される、というシステムです。

なお、現在このサイトはベータ期間中なので、権限に必要な信用度が全体的に低めに設定されています。例えば[本家SOでクローズ票を投じるには3,000点必要](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)ですが、[現在の日本語版では500点](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)です。ベータを卒業してこれらの基準が元通りになった時にも、基準を満たさなくなった権限は失うことになります。